# Minimum Variance Unbiased Estimator for Exponential Family of Distribution

Tags: probability, statistics

Let $X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n$ be a random sample from distribution with pmf $p(x;θ)=\theta^x(1−θ),x=0,1,2,…;0$ elsewhere, $0≤θ≤1$. I know that $Y_1=\sum_1^n X_i$ is a sufficient statistic for $θ$ because this pmf itself comes from family of exponential distribution. The expectation for sufficient statistic is
$$E[Y_1]=n\frac{1−θ}{θ}$$
How do I find a function of Y1 that is an unbiased estimator for $θ$? I tried algebraically solving it and the function is $\varphi(Y_1)=\frac{n}{Y_1+n}=\frac{1}{\frac{Y_1}{n}+1}$. Is this correct? I'm not sure how to find the $\mathbb{E}[\varphi(Y_1)]$ though.

Comment: I replaced the [tag:probability-theory] tag by [tag:probability]. Please avail yourself of the tag summaries when choosing tags.

Comment: Your expectation is the wrong way around; it should be $\frac{n\theta}{1-\theta}$.